# Islam, Islamic countries, and Islamic law

Tags: discussion

This is partially spurred on by this question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/917/how-come-in-saudi-arabia-females-are-not-allowed-to-leave-without-permission-d

While I feel the wording could use a bit of work, I feel that we need to address questions pertaining to laws which are alleged to have Islamic roots.  Not only is this (laws) the only exposure that a large number of people have, but it will clarify what is actually Islamic ideas/sharia law and what is just an *interpretation* of Islamic ideas/sharia law.

Answer (score 1):

To address this question specifically:

The reason it is off-topic is that it is about the laws of Saudi Arabia. Now, this may be an Islamic law, but that's the only relation.

This site is for questions about Islam. Questions about *Muslims* or *Islamic Countries* are off topic.

Comment: But what if those customs or laws are derived from either "Islam" or "Islamic cultures" of the past?

Comment: @Ansari, then the question can be phrase to be about Islam, not laws of some countries. For example, one can ask "Are females permitted to leave their house without the permission of their guardian?".

Comment: @Ansari Exactly what Kaveh said.